# How to split string in JavaScript with splitter?

Tags: javascript, string

can we split the input string with splitter `/* ! */`

I have string

```
var a ="/*! ###################################################### # Test.cs #  RELEASE: 1.1.1 # BUILD DATE: Fri Oct 30 2020 15:25:57 GMT-0700 (PDT) # COPYRIGHT ###################################################### *//*! MISC + SASS */a:focus,button:focus,div[tabindex]:focus,li[tabindex]:focus,span[tabindex]:focus{outline-offset:2px;outline-width:2px!important;outline-style:dotted!important;outline-color:currentColor}/*! GENERIC - BGIMG */.bgimg{background-size:cover;background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat}/*! CG2111 - test */span{color:red}/*! CG2112 - test */span{color:red}/*! INFO */#id{content:'1.1.1'}"
```

I am trying to split string using commented code `/* ! */`

Expected output

```
{
  "MISC + SASS " : "span[tabindex]:focus,
  li[tabindex]:focus,
  div[tabindex]:focus,
  button:focus,
  a:focus {
    outline-offset: 2px;
    outline-width: 2px !important;
    outline-style: dotted !important;
    outline-color: currentColor;
  }",
  "GENERIC - BGIMG":".bgimg {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }",
  "CG2111 - test":"span {
    color: red;
  }",
  "CG2112 - test":"span {
    color: red;
  }",
  "INFO":"#id {
    content: '1.1.1';
  }"


}
```

or store in array only value.

Comment: You can split a string with [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: split is supposed to return an array but your expected output is an object...

Comment: This is not string splitting. Splitting takes some string of the form `axb`, `axbxc`, `axbxcxd...` etc. where x is some arbitrary string sequence that is considered "glue", to be removed during splitting, leaving you with a list of the separate, constituent parts `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. What you're showing is something completely different, far more akin to tokenizing/parsing. So please update your post to explain what you're _actually_ trying to do: what is the input? (what does it represent) and what is the output? (what does _it_ represent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using a regex to split it into an array based on the `/*! ... */` structure.

```js
const a = "/*! ###################################################### # Test.cs #  RELEASE: 1.1.1 # BUILD DATE: Fri Oct 30 2020 15:25:57 GMT-0700 (PDT) # COPYRIGHT ###################################################### *//*! MISC + SASS */a:focus,button:focus,div[tabindex]:focus,li[tabindex]:focus,span[tabindex]:focus{outline-offset:2px;outline-width:2px!important;outline-style:dotted!important;outline-color:currentColor}/*! GENERIC - BGIMG */.bgimg{background-size:cover;background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat}/*! CG2111 - test */span{color:red}/*! CG2112 - test */span{color:red}/*! INFO */#id{content:'1.1.1'}";

const result = {}, temp = a.split(/\/\*\!\s*(.*?)\s*\*\//).slice(1);
while (temp.length) result[temp.shift()] = temp.shift();

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sequence `*//*!` will always be a part of your string(just before the beginning of your expected result):

```js
const a ="/*! ###################################################### # Test.cs #  RELEASE: 1.1.1 # BUILD DATE: Fri Oct 30 2020 15:25:57 GMT-0700 (PDT) # COPYRIGHT ###################################################### *//*! MISC + SASS */a:focus,button:focus,div[tabindex]:focus,li[tabindex]:focus,span[tabindex]:focus{outline-offset:2px;outline-width:2px!important;outline-style:dotted!important;outline-color:currentColor}/*! GENERIC - BGIMG */.bgimg{background-size:cover;background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat}/*! CG2111 - test */span{color:red}/*! CG2112 - test */span{color:red}/*! INFO */#id{content:'1.1.1'}";

const arr = a.split('*//*!');
const arr2 = arr[1].split('/*!');

const obj = {};
for(const item of arr2){
  const tmp = item.split('*/');
  obj[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
}
console.log(obj);
```